# print all unmet dependencies in conda

Tags: conda, conda-forge, mamba

I'm trying to install a package via `conda` on an M1 mac. This package has a lot of dependencies, some of which seem to be un-satisfiable due to lack of pre-built packages in `conda-forge`.

I know I can trigger building of packages in `conda-forge` by issuing a PR like shown [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/pull/4529), but I'd prefer sending **one big PR** with all the packages I need built, rather than trigger building of package A, trying to install, running into dependency B, trigger building of package B, ...

Can I somehow list *all* unmet dependencies of a conda package?

Comment: Great question! Made me learn some new Mamba tricks. Note I'm adding the `mamba` tag because it is what Conda Forge primarily uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Trivial case: directly missing package

First, let's note that this question only has a non-trivial answer when the package in question is **noarch**. A **noarch** designation means the package itself is already compatible with **osx-arm64**. But if it cannot be installed with a plain `mamba install`, then some non-**noarch** (compiled) dependency(s) must be missing.

Otherwise, if the package were not **noarch** and does not itself have **osx-arm64** builds, then [requesting migration for that package](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#apple-silicon-builds) would trigger both the package and *all its (recursive) dependencies* to be made available for **osx-arm64**. (Conda Forge bot is smart like that!)

I'm not assuming OP has any confusion about this, but I want to get ahead of this situation for the future visitors. Now that that's out of the way let's address OP's question proper...

### Available package, but missing dependencies

We can absolutely do this with Mamba's amazing subcommand `repoquery`. Let's find ourselves a concrete example!

##### Finding an example

To illustrate, I know that Conda Forge doesn't have `r-terra` building for **osx-arm64** right now<sup>**1**</sup>. We can use the `mamba repoquery whoneeds` command to list every **noarch** package that needs **r-terra**:

```bash
## search `conda-forge` and only consider `noarch`
$ mamba repoquery whoneeds -c conda-forge -p noarch r-terra

## abridged output, only showing r-base=4.2 packages

 Name         Version Build         Depends          Channel
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 r-rasterdiv  0.2_5.2 r42hc72bb7e_1 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-rastervis  0.51.2  r42hc72bb7e_1 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-biomod2    4.2_2   r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra >=1.6_33 conda-forge/noarch
 r-biomod2    4.2_3   r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra >=1.6_33 conda-forge/noarch
 r-rasterdiv  0.3.1   r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-rastervis  0.51.4  r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-rastervis  0.51.5  r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-spatialeco 2.0_0   r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-rasterdiv  0.2_5.2 r42hc72bb7e_1 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-rastervis  0.51.2  r42hc72bb7e_1 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-biomod2    4.2_2   r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra >=1.6_33 conda-forge/noarch
 r-biomod2    4.2_3   r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra >=1.6_33 conda-forge/noarch
 r-rasterdiv  0.3.1   r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-rastervis  0.51.4  r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-rastervis  0.51.5  r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
 r-spatialeco 2.0_0   r42hc72bb7e_0 r-terra          conda-forge/noarch
```

So, all of these are theoretically compatible with **osx-arm64**, but they depend on the package `r-terra` that isn't available yet.

Let's use for our example, `r-spatialeco`.

##### Missing dependencies of `r-spatialeco`

Above we used the `whoneeds` subcommand for a reverse dependency search; now we'll use the `depends` command for (forward) dependency search:

```bash
$ mamba repoquery depends -c conda-forge -p osx-arm64 r-spatialeco

Executing the query r-spatialeco

conda-forge/osx-arm64                                       Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache


 Name                            Version Build         Channel
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 r-spatialeco                    2.0_0   r41hc72bb7e_0 conda-forge/noarch
 r-mass                          7.3_53  r40h4d528fc_0 conda-forge/osx-arm64
 r-cluster                       2.1.0   r40h09a9d6b_4 conda-forge/osx-arm64
 r-rcurl >>> NOT FOUND <<<
 r-readr                         2.0.2   r40h8ea1354_0 conda-forge/osx-arm64
 r-sf >>> NOT FOUND <<<
 r-mgcv                          1.8_33  r40hdd02fd4_0 conda-forge/osx-arm64
 r-rann                          2.6.1   r40h39468a4_2 conda-forge/osx-arm64
 r-envstats                      2.3.1   r351_1000     conda-forge/noarch
 r-yaimpute >>> NOT FOUND <<<
 r-spdep >>> NOT FOUND <<<
 r-rms >>> NOT FOUND <<<
 r-terra >>> NOT FOUND <<<
 r-ks                            1.14.0  r41h5d63f41_0 conda-forge/osx-arm64
 r-spatstat.explore              3.0_5   r41h5d63f41_0 conda-forge/osx-arm64
 r-base                          4.1.3   hc39b4fc_7    conda-forge/osx-arm64
 r-spatialpack >>> NOT FOUND <<<
 r-spatstat.geom                 3.2_1   r42h21dc0da_0 conda-forge/osx-arm64
```

And there you have it: the `r-spatialeco` package is missing seven packages that need to be migrated to **osx-arm64**, as indicated by the `>>> NOT FOUND <<<` string.

---

<sub>**[1]:** I know this because I've taken a stab at getting it migrated multiple times and have yet to succeed. :/</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain all of this, this is fantastic!

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled still: Even though the command `mamba repoquery depends -c bioconda -c conda-forge -p osx-arm64 bioconductor-siamcat ` shows that all dependencies are now available (either in `noarch` or in `osx-arm64`), installation with `mamba install -c bioconda bioconductor-siamcat` still fails with `nothing provides r-mlr needed by bioconductor-siamcat-1.10.0-r40_0`

Extra confusing since `r-mlr` isn't listed as an initial dependency...

Comment: @PejoPhylo the report only considers the immediate dependencies. So, if one of those is **noarch**, then it could still be hiding a compiled dependency further down the DAG. You can add a `--recursive` flag to literally list everything that must be installed.

Comment: thanks! I assume you mean `--tree` ? `--recursive` doesn't seem to exist as a flag for `mamba repoquery depends` and `--tree` seems to list dependencies hierarchically down the DAG